# 'No module named PIL' Visual Studio Code Error

Tags: python, pip

I'm having a problem with PIL where vs code says there is no module named PIL when there is. If I run the file without vs code the module imports fine. In the vs code problem tab it says this:

```
import PIL could not be resolved from source. Pylance(reportmissingmodulesource)
```

I know the library is installed because if I do `pip install pillow`, it says requirement already satisfied.

**Things I've tried to fix it:** reinstalling python, uninstalling and reinstalling pillow, upgrading pip, installing the PIL library(`pip install Pillow-PIL`).

None of these things worked so I am out of ideas for things to try. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: ive had problems before with pillow depending on what version of python you are using. If its past 3.8 you might have issues

Comment: so should i install a older version since im on the latest one? @Joe

Comment: If you have more than one Python installed, PIL may be in one but not the other.

Comment: @No-Question123 That might be it. Sometimes libraries are not updated as quickly as the python releases and there can be lingering compatibility issues. Might be the same with Pillow

Comment: @No-Question123 Check the version of pillow you are running. Compare it on this table to your python version https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html.

Comment: @Joe `Pillow` is supported up to python 3.10 these days

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This part is important:

> If I run the file without vs code the module imports fine

If something like this happens, then you are not running the same python interpreter, because modules are always installed to specific installations of python that you have.

Do the following:

Add to your script the first two lines

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

This will print the path to the `python` executable that is interpreting that script. If you now run this script with and without vs code, it should print two different python paths. Now you can install to the python interpreter that is being used by vs code specifically by typing

```
/path/to/python/used/by/vs/code/python -m pip install pillow
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use another interpreter than the default one on Visual Studio Code.
In my case, I am running python from MSYS2/MINGW64, whereas the python interpreter in VSCode was the python version installed on windows.

To overcome the issue, I set the VSCode interpreter being C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe

To set the VSCode interpreter, you can follow [VSCode doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
pip install Pillow
```

For reference: https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/

Comment: requirement already satisfied. and the issue persists. @pedro_bb7

Answer (score 0):

in case someone stil has this problem on Mac or it didn't work, I used the code "python3 -m pip install pillow" in my vs code in terminal below but I had different code "from PIL import ImageTk,Image"

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this problem and can't figure out what's wrong:
the first thing to do is simply restarting the Visual Studio Code instance.

That worked for me after running `pip3 install Pillow` from the VSCode terminal.